# What is the encoding of CompletedProcess.stdout coming from Powershell/Windows in Python?

Tags: python, powershell, encoding, subprocess

I am getting this output from a ping request started from Python with `subprocess.run()`:

```py
>>> process.stdout
b"\r\nEnvoi d'une requ\x88te 'ping' sur www.google.fr [142.250.179.195] avec 32 octets de donn\x82es\xff:\r\nR\x82ponse de 142.250.179.195\xff: octets=32 temps=39 ms TTL=110\r\nR\x82ponse de 142.250.179.195\xff: octets=32 temps=46 ms TTL=110\r\nR\x82ponse de 142.250.179.195\xff: octets=32 temps=37 ms TTL=110\r\n\r\nStatistiques Ping pour 142.250.179.195:\r\n    Paquets\xff: envoy\x82s = 3, re\x87us = 3, perdus = 0 (perte 0%),\r\nDur\x82e approximative des boucles en millisecondes :\r\n    Minimum = 37ms, Maximum = 46ms, Moyenne = 40ms\r\n"
```

I run this script from Pycharm that runs Powershell on a Windows 10 21H2 in French language. So I expect encoding Windows-1252. Which is also the guess of chardet:

```py
>>> chardet.detect(process.stdout)
{'encoding': 'Windows-1252', 'confidence': 0.73, 'language': ''}
```

However decoding this with Windows-1252 does not look very right:

```py
>>> process.stdout.decode("windows-1252")
"\r\nEnvoi d'une requˆte 'ping' sur www.google.fr [142.250.179.195] avec 32 octets de donn‚esÿ:\r\nR‚ponse de 142.250.179.195ÿ: octets=32 temps=39 ms TTL=110\r\nR‚ponse de 142.250.179.195ÿ: octets=32 temps=46 ms TTL=110\r\nR‚ponse de 142.250.179.195ÿ: octets=32 temps=37 ms TTL=110\r\n\r\nStatistiques Ping pour 142.250.179.195:\r\n    Paquetsÿ: envoy‚s = 3, re‡us = 3, perdus = 0 (perte 0%),\r\nDur‚e approximative des boucles en millisecondes :\r\n    Minimum = 37ms, Maximum = 46ms, Moyenne = 40ms\r\n"
```

0x88 should be `ê` and 0x82 should be `è`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Console* applications on Windows typically use the console's active code page to encode their output, which by default is the system's legacy *OEM* code page (e.g., [`CP437`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CP437) on US-English systems), not the legacy *ANSI* code page used by *GUI* applications (e.g, [`Windows-1252`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252)):

You can use the following code to determine the console's active code page and decode based on it:

```py
import ctypes
import subprocess

# Get the console's active code page, as an integer.
oemCP = ctypes.windll.kernel32.GetConsoleOutputCP()

process = subprocess.run('ping.exe', capture_output=True)

# Decode based on the console's active code page.
print(process.stdout.decode("cp" + str(oemCP)))
```

---

A note re *detecting* the coding:

- The prevalent single-byte code pages that are used as the OEM and ANSI code pages do not use BOMs, and *any* byte value is also a valid character.
- This ultimately makes any attempt to detect what an unknown encoding is *guesswork* - though the probability of guessing right can be improved with sophisticated linguistic analysis.
- I don't know what approach `chardet.detect()` uses, but in this case it guessed incorrectly; that it *guessed* can be inferred from the presence of a `confidence` value.

> `0x88` should be `ê` and `0x82` should be `è`

This actually applies to CP437, not to Windows-1252, as the following PowerShell code demonstrates:

```sh
PS> [System.Text.Encoding]::GetEncoding(437).GetString([byte[]] (0x88, 0x82))

êé
```

Answer (score 1):

If any one lands here, small working snipped based on [mklement0](https://stackoverflow.com/users/45375/mklement0) answer.

```
import locale
import ctypes
import subprocess

oemCP = ctypes.windll.kernel32.GetConsoleOutputCP()
print(f'{locale.getpreferredencoding()=}')

encoding = "cp" + str(oemCP)
print(f"{encoding=}")

p = subprocess.run('dir c:\\',
                   shell=True,
                   stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                   universal_newlines=True,
                   encoding=encoding,
                   stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)

print(p.stdout)
```